# mysql cast as interval

Tags: mysql, casting, intervals

is it possible to cast as an interval in MySQL?

I want to evaluate a value from the query as an interval, like this:

```
select DATE_SUB(NOW(),CAST(user.expiry_interval AS interval))
```

where user.expiry_interval is 'INTERVAL 1 WEEK' or something like that

```
select DATE_SUB(NOW(),CAST('INTERVAL 1 week' AS INTERVAL))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a string/column value as a mysql date interval constant (DAY, MONTH...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888971/how-to-use-a-string-column-value-as-a-mysql-date-interval-constant-day-month)

Comment: the question you linked to was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`INTERVAL` is not a data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html), but a [keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) that converts a human-readable "duration" string into an integer. As such, "casting to `INTERVAL`" makes no sense.

If your "interval" input is variable, then this can work but you can't take the entire thing from a string any more than you can "cast" the string `"SELECT * FROM tbl"` into a query expression. You can use a variable for the numeric operand (see below) but I think that's it.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `x` DAY) FROM `tbl`;
```

You'll have to resort to `CASE` if you want logic that's stronger than that. Or... store integer durations in the first place.