# Mysql DATE_ADD INTERVAL with mysql table fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table called datas in there I have `id`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`day_count`,`day_type`.
Where `id` is primary key,start and `end_date` is datetime, `day_count` is int and `day_type` is varchar.
Now day_type store DAY,WEEK,MONTH as value when user made request and day field hold number of days like 1 to 60.

Now I want to user this count and type in date_add mysql built-in function.

I have tried to pass it as below but its show error.

```
SELECT
datas.day_count,
datas.day_type,
MIN( datas.start_date ) AS MinDate,
MAX( datas.end_date ) AS MaxDate, 
DATE_ADD(MaxDate,INTERVAL datas.day_count datas.day_type) AS ExactDate,
datas.trade_service_id
FROM datas
```

Erro is 

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'datas.day_type)) AS ExactDate, datas' at line 13`

Please little hint would be great.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the error you are getting.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888971/how-to-use-a-string-column-value-as-a-mysql-date-interval-constant-day-month

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This query works in MySQL but what do you exactly want to output without Group and so on?

```
SELECT
datas.day_count,
datas.day_type,
MIN( datas.start_date ) AS MinDate,
MAX( datas.end_date ) AS MaxDate,

start_date, min(start_date) as min_date,
case day_type 
  when 'MONTH' then DATE_ADD(MAX( datas.end_date ),INTERVAL datas.day_count MONTH) 
  when 'DAY' then DATE_ADD(MAX( datas.end_date ),INTERVAL datas.day_count DAY) 
end as ExactDate,

datas.trade_service_id
FROM datas
```

Comment: exactly what I needed to know, that I can't use a field as the interval type. CASE works fine as an alternative.