# How to add another column's integer value to a date column?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add an integer to a date but I get the following error:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(wp.OrderDate, INTERVAL WPProduct.Duration DAY) AS ExpiryDate FROM wp' at line 6*

```
SELECT 
wp.customers_id, 
wp.OrderDate, 
wp.products_id,
WPProduct.Duration,
DATE_ADD (wp.OrderDate, INTERVAL WPProduct.Duration DAY) AS ExpiryDate
FROM wp 
INNER JOIN WPProduct ON WPProduct.products_id = wp.products_id
WHERE wp.customers_id = 2
```

Comment: post your tables' schmas

Comment: Is `WPProduce.Duration` allowed to be null?  It might not like the possibility of adding a null value to date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a string/column value as a mysql date interval constant (DAY, MONTH...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888971/how-to-use-a-string-column-value-as-a-mysql-date-interval-constant-day-month)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp` (
  `user` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  
  `OrderDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`user`),
  UNIQUE KEY `customers_id` (`customers_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove whitespace after DATE_ADD:

```
SELECT 
wp.customers_id, 
wp.OrderDate, 
wp.products_id,
WPProduct.Duration,
DATE_ADD(wp.OrderDate, INTERVAL WPProduct.Duration DAY) AS ExpiryDate
FROM wp 
INNER JOIN WPProduct ON WPProduct.products_id = wp.products_id
WHERE wp.customers_id = 2
```