# Add integer value from another column to date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I want to add the value of another colum (which is an an integer representing miliseconds) to a date value in an update query.
I tried what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672906/6042077) suggests but I can't find a way to not hardcode the value in the query but instead read it from the other column.

The two relevant fields are:

```
ScheduledExecuteDate: DATE(6)
RecurringInterval: INTEGER representing the number of miliseconds to add to the date
```

My query looks something like this:

```
UPDATE "Tasks" SET 
"ScheduledExecuteDate"="ScheduledExecuteDate" + interval ("RecurringInterval" / 1000) second 
WHERE "id" = 62
```

I've also tried `'second'`. In both cases it throws an syntax error "at or near second"
Also note that I have to wrap the column names in quotes since they are case sensitive.

I also tried

```
"scheduledExecuteDate"=DATE_ADD("scheduledExecuteDate", interval ("Tasks"."recurringInterval" / 1000) seconds)
```

like answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34439510/6042077)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `make_interval()` passing fractional seconds:

```
UPDATE "Tasks" 
  SET "ScheduledExecuteDate" = "ScheduledExecuteDate" 
                               + make_interval(secs => "RecurringInterval"::double precision / 1000) second 
WHERE "id" = 62
```