# DATE_ADD doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in MySQL. Staff with fields id, name, surname, telephone, adress, id_work.

Work with fields id, name.

Absence with fields id, name, id_staff start_date and duration.

I have the following query:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM staff s 
     JOIN work w
       ON s.id_work = w.id 
LEFT JOIN absence a 
       ON s.id = a.id_staff AND a.name = 'vacations' 
    WHERE (w.name='sales manager' AND a.id_staff IS NULL) 
       OR (w.name='sales manager') 
      AND (a.start_date>NOW () OR DATE_ADD (a.start_date,INTERVAL a.duration DAY)< NOW ())
```

I want to study the case of  existing employees that have not absense and the case of existing employees that having absense but this is not priogramming for today. The main concept is this query returns the staff of a business who is present. 
My problem is that a person who has totaly two abseses e.g. one was for 11/7/2017 and the duration was for 10 days and another is for 19/8/2017 and the duration is for 5 days , the query returns count (*)=1 which is wrong. I want to display count (*)=0 because today this employee is present in his job

Comment: Your query is sufficiently confusing that I would say you should include sample data and your expected output in the question.

Comment: I don't think you can use the duration field directly to specify the interval. MySQL expects a keyword. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293343/5947043 . Even if it does work how you've got it, I think the query will count the number of absences where the start date is > now, which includes your future absence. But yeah some proper sample data would be best. And check the operator precedence in your ON clause.

Comment: Please replace `COUNT(*)` with the columns from the WHERE clause and show us the rows which in your opinion do not match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
OR DATE_ADD(a.start_date, INTERVAL a.duration DAY) < NOW ()
```

Comment: I change it but the problem exists. It continues to display count=0

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in DATE_ADD condition, please make the schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ if possibe

Answer (score 0):

your condition `OR (w.name='sales manager')` adds ALL the cases where `w.name = sales Manager` you Need to put brackets around the first two conditions (i think)

EDIT:
i mean like this

```
    WHERE ((w.name='sales manager' AND a.id_staff IS NULL) 
       OR w.name='sales manager')
```

but it doesn't make sense, since the first condition is negated by the second, and i don't really understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Mabye you parenthesis ?